# Wordpress Multisite URL change - wp-admin not found

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I changed the URL of my Wordpress page. It's a multisite network.
I did most of the changes on the database.

These tables were affected:

```
wp_options: options named “siteurl” and “home”
wp_site 
wp_sitemeta: the option named “siteurl” 
wp_blogs: any entries in the “domains” column that have the old domain name
wp_#_options: Each sub-site will have sets of tables that correspond to the blog_id in the wp_blogs table. You need to go to the wp_#_options table, where # corresponds to the blog_id, and update the “siteurl” and “home” settings in that table.
```

Now when I try to access the admin panel with the new domain  `newdomain.subdomain.com/wp-admin/` I get the error:`**Not Found The requested URL /wp-admin/ was not found on this server.**`

What is still missing?

Comment: I think Wordpress cant figure out where the path of the page is on the server.

Comment: try site/wp-admin/index.php, maybe if you put `index.php` it will work

Comment: Did you change the domain or did you move the WP install to another domain?

Comment: I changed the domain name, same WP install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the new domain is pointing to the same folder as the old domain. I had a situation like this where the new domain was not pointing to the same server as the old domain, and after fixing that. I usually put an html file in the root to make sure that I can call it from both the old and the new domains, before updating the WordPress site URL.

Also, have a look in your `wp-config.php` there's a line like this `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domainname.old');`, update it to the correct domain.

Comment: `define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'sub.domain.tld');` won't keep you out of wp-admin/ in a WP Multisite Network, in fact it can be commented out.
When DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE is defined, it overrides the value in <wp_db>.wp_site.domain, either of which sets the domain portion of urls for My Sites > Network Admin > ...
At least in a `define ('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);` aka a sub-domain network, you can think of WP as a gateway to all sub-domains, whose doc roots all point to the main WP install dir, where WP takes over and sends the WP content based on the requested domain name.

Comment: True @DWB, I added that because I was not sure if the OP was referring to the Main WP or Sub Domain, hence I added that comment as an additional check to do. In my case, I had actually changed the Main WP domain, hence the error.